# How do I make an asynchronous call using AngularJs and Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

This seems like a very simple question but being new to Javascript, Typescript and Angular I can't seem to find an answer (I have looked believe me).

I just want to make a simple request to a server and handle a result. This is actually as part of an OAuth authentication process: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken

I have found a lot of references to $http.get but I not sure how to call this from within Typescript.
I also saw people talking about JQuery promises but I believe that I shouldn't need to use JQuery if I am already using Angular.

I have had a look at my angular.d.ts file and it looks like I should be using the IHttpService but how do I instantiate one of these? How do I use the generics with the get method?
An example of how to do this would be great.

Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you are new to javascript and want to use angular, I would suggest you don't use typescript at the beginning as you will have a harder time finding demos and examples that use typescript. Since TypeScript is a subset of Javascript learn the javascript part first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do some research into how to do oauth specifically with angular. Typing into Google 'angular oauth'  should be a good starting point. The first result should be this tutorial.

http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/tutorials/how-to-implement-safe-signin-via-oauth

It is safe to assume someone has already implemented oauth and made it available as a maintained module. It may be best to look for such a module.

https://www.google.ie/search?site=&source=hp&ei=IPWWVOqZEePe7AbI8YH4Dg&q=angularjs+oauth+module&oq=angularjs+oauth+module&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.12...2447.2447.0.3443.2.2.0.1.1.0.203.406.2-2.2.0.msedr...0...1c.2.60.mobile-gws-hp..1.1.88.3.KF2tzFFu2RI

**Edit** Specific to how to call a async enpoint using TypeScript and Angular:

Don't use jQuery with Angular. If you are new to JavaScript and have not used jQuery, it is best not to use it with Angular. jQuery is great. But if you are learning Angular you are better off not using it.

Controllers and Services in Angular are prototype constructor. These are expresses in TypeScript as classes. Any class, or prototype constructor, that you **register with the `service()` method in angular is automatically registered as a singleton**.

Example

```
// this is a ts module
// we put our code in here to not polute global scope
// angular modules are different -- don't confuse them
module app {

    // we export the class so that we can access its API from
    // tests. We don't ever want to directly new it from tests though.
    // we should always use $injector.get('myService') to get the test instance.
    export class MyService {

        // We need to tell angular what service to inject.
        // Using the $inject annotation is the cleanest way.
        // Our $inject and constructor are on top of each other
        // this way. We can see that they match
        // As well, we use the type ng.IHttpService with on $http 
        static $inject = ['$http']; 
        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {}

            getMyEndpoint() {

                return this.$http.get('http://myendpoint.com/myendpoint');

            }
    }

    // here we register this class as a singleton by using the
    // .singleton method. 
    angular.module('app').service('myService', MyService);
}
```

For controllers it is similar. For this example we will bring in the singleton service we just created.

```
module app {

    export class MyController {

        data: MyData[];

        static $inject = ['myService'];
        constructor(myService: MyService) {

            myService.getMyEndpoint().then(
                 (data) => {
                     this.data = data;
                 }
            );
        }

    }
    angular.module('app').controller('MyController', MyController);
}
```

Notice above we do not pass the $scope into the controller. Instead we put the results of the service call on a public member of the class. We can then access this in the view using the controllerAs syntax. This is more desirable then passing $scopes into controllers and binding to them, as they suffer from scope inheritance. They have the same drawbacks as global scopes. You will run into scope collision eventually. Read up on controllerAs syntax.

You will notice we use pascal-case `MyController` to register controllers and camel-case `myServcie` to register services. This is to distinguish that when a class is registered as a controller, a new instance of it is returned each time it is retrieved. Services are singletons. It is only newed once by angular. Only a single instance is returned.

Because we export the class APIs for use in testing (but not to be newed up in test, or anywhere in our application) , we will want to wrap our application in a closure at build time. Uglifyjs can do this for us.

Finally, Google 'basarat angular typescript' to read and watch many tutorials on angular and typescript from @basarat.

Comment: I'm sure these are good references, but OP's question wasn't really about OAuth at all.

Comment: The OP is trying to accomplish OAuth. It is better to see how this is accomplished using Angular rather than to tell OP to just use the $httpservice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was wanting advice more about how to use angular and Typescript rather than specifically help on oAuth. I am sure that there is a module available for this but I am using this as a learning experience to get used to some new technologies. I have implemented OAuth before in other languages so this is a good way to learn.

Comment: Specific to your question, TypeScript is a superset of Javascript. So there is nothing typescript specific you will need to use the $http service. You do want to make sure you have the angular.d.ts type definitions in your project so that you can use the ng.IHttpService interface in the injection. With TS you should define your controller and services as classes. I will try to update my original answer with examples if I get to a computer.

Comment: Many Thanks. I was planning on getting to the dependency injection bit of Angular later but it seems that it's hard to use any of it without going all in. I am familiar with IOC and constructor injection as I use Parsley with Flex in my day job.

Comment: Just read through this in a bit more detail and it really is very useful, thanks. I am just getting to implement my first controller and I really don't like the idea of injecting a scope and setting everything on that. The controllerAs method seems much nicer.
Also thanks for the nice tip about the PascalCase vs camleCase convention.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example, how I create the Service:

```
module MyApp.MyModule
{
    export class SecuritySvc
    {
        private root : string;

        static $inject = ["$http"];

        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService)
        {
            this.root = "api/";
        }

        public getRoles()
        : ng.IHttpPromise<IRole[]>
        {
            var url = this.root + "Security/Roles";
            return this.$http.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
        }
        ...
        // many others
    }
}
```

This way we can inject that into angular

```
angular.module("MyApp.MyModule")
    .service("SecuritySvc", MyApp.MyModule.SecuritySvc)
```

And then use it like this, for example in *my* controller

```
module MyApp.MyModule
{
    export interface IMyScope extends ng.IScope
    {
        Roles:  IRole[];
    }

    export class MyCtrl
    {
        static $inject = ['$scope', "SecuritySvc", ...];

        constructor(public $scope: ng.IRootScopeService
                  , public SecuritySvc: SecuritySvc
                  , ... )
        {
            SecuritySvc
                .getRoles()
                .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IRole[]>) =>
                {
                    var roles = response.data;
                    this.$scope.Roles = roles;
                    ...
```

And controller is defined like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp.MyModule')
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyApp.MyModule.MyCtrl);
```

Comment: Many Thanks for this. I wish I could mark both as answers but the other poster goes into a bit more detail and did answer first.

Comment: As you want. My answer was from the beginning complete, while the other was later extended based on mine... Anyhow good luck with `Typescript`. This is the way to go.